How to make synchronous API calls and return chainable in a function?
Here is what I am trying to do in the code below.

Make three API calls inside the function areAllTypesFound.
Use the results of those API calls to decide whether I got all the necessary data.

If I get all the necessary data from the calls, then return a boolean wrapped inside a chainable.

In the function doStuff, I make a call to areAllTypesFound. only after that call is completed, I will do something with the boolean result. After that, I will execute some more code.


The problem is that areAllTypesFound always returns false even when all the data is found. I am quite sure this has to do something with the async nature of Cypress. Can someone please show me how to execute everything synchronously in the below code?
class MyClass {

    static areAllTypesFound(params) : Cypress.Chainable<boolean> {
        let idsType1 : number[];
        let idsType2 :number[];
        let idsType3 :number[];

        let [type1Present, type2Present, type3Present] = [false, false, false];

        // Here response = Cypress.Response<ItemType1 2 or 3>
        ApiCaller.getItemType1(param1).then((response) => {
            idsType1 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
            type1Present = idsType1.length > 0;
        }
    
        ApiCaller.getItemType2(param2).then((response) => {
            idsType2 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
            type2Present = idsType2.length > 0;
        }

        ApiCaller.getItemType3(param3).then((response) => {
            idsType3 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
            type3Present = idsType3.length > 0;
        }

        const allTypesPresent = type1Present && type2Present && type3Present;
        // optional - maybe print all the "idsType" arrays.

        return cy.wrap(allTypesPresent);
    } 

    static doStuff() : void {
        this.areAllTypesFound(params).then((areFoundBoolean) => {
            if(areFoundBoolean) {
                // do something
            }else {
                // do something else
            }
        });

        // do more stuff only AFTER the above code is completed !
    }

}

Sample code for what itemType function looks like -
  public static getItemType1<T = ItemType1>(param1: string): Cypress.Chainable<Cypress.Response<T>> {
    return cy.request({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/items/itemType1",
      qs: {
        itemType: param1,
      },
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
  }


@HereticMonkey - unfortunately, no. My question is about cypress which uses .then() blocks for handling code synchronously. The question which you posted is about plain javascript and not cypress. Also, I use cypress with typescript and not javascript. So there are differences

Please show the code you have for each getItemType. Obviously you have to chain calls to make them sequential, but cannot say how to do that unless you show us the precise  Cypress commands, not just some testing wrapper calls.

then blocks are not handled synchronously. That mistake is why you're having issues. TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript. Valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript.

Heretic Monkey is correct, your code is not synchronous, and this is a common (and solved) problem. Your impression that Cypress somehow makes this different is mistaken.

Cypress uses a queue system and does not return promises. That makes it slightly different from the "normal" async/await pattern.

@AladinSpaz that's true but that doesn't make it synchronous.

BTW, I don't know why people keep insisting that my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. Yeah, typescript will get transpiled to javascript. But, I want to know how I can make synchronous function calls with cypress (if that is even possible). If you can do that, then feel free to answer.

@JarradSmith - Correct, but the proposed duplicate question is a mish-mash of different solutions to the asynchronous problem, and some of them show async/await pattern. The problem is, anybody looking for guidance on this particular Cypress problem will be thoroughly confused by that answer.

I do think there is already a Cypress-specific answer out there, I just have to find it. In the meantime, I presented my answer to clarify what IMO is the way to solve, but will delete it when I find a prior example. I also think there can be a more elegant solution, perhaps a variation on what @agoff has proposed.

@AladinSpaz - Someone here is on a mission to close my question without realizing that its not a duplicate. If you think its really not a duplicate, then could you please reopen it? I'd really like to ask that person for a solution since they insist its a duplicate of some unrelated javascript question.

Yeah, I've seen this before (maybe the same question used to close a similar Cypress problem). Maybe if you spent a week going through the linked info you get some helpful insights, but it seems to go against the spirit of SO to have concise, reproducible questions and answers that can be a reference for future users. That's why I try to add a reproducible example in the answer, hopefully a good representation of the original problem. Having said that, some problems are a lot of work to reproduce.

@MasterJoe speaking as one of those people: I was wrong, I agree with AladinSpaz that while it may technically be a duplicate the other answers don't directly help you enough, and I've voted to reopen your question. That being said... your question implies that you have fundamental misunderstandings about how Javascript works, and that makes it very tempting to close your question on first impressions alone. That you would ask about a synchronous API call strongly implies that you didn't even do a google-search's worth of effort to know it was impossible.

You could nest the API calls. There may be a more elegant way, but nesting the calls and returning at each level ensures you have completed each call before the final return is made.
const allResults = []  // gather the results in an array

return ApiCaller.getItemType1(param1).then((response) => {
  idsType1 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
  allResults.push(idsType1)
    
  return ApiCaller.getItemType2(param2).then((response) => {
    idsType2 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
    allResults.push(idsType2)

    return ApiCaller.getItemType3(param3).then((response) => {
      idsType2 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
      allResults.push(idsType2)
 
      return allResults
    }
  }
}

You can put anything in the allResults, as long as you get 3 things in the array.

An Example
I wanted to explore the code in question in a reproducible form.
There's a useful website requestly.com

Build, Test & Debug your web apps faster by Intercepting & Modifying Network Traffic, Session Replays, Mock Server & API Client.

This site can add delays (or other modifications) to your cy.request() calls, which allows you to stress-test your test code to make sure it's not flaky.
The way you use it is to embed the delay time in milliseconds and the actual API URL like this:
https://app.requestly.io/delay/<delay_in_millisecods>/<URL_to_be_delayed

The API I want to test is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/, requesting records with id's  1, 2, and 3.
The goal is to ensure all three results are returned from the function (or in the OP it's a class method, same idea).
function apiCalls() {
  const myApiBase = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'
  const urlWithDelay = 'https://app.requestly.io/delay/1000/' + myApiBase

  return cy.request(urlWithDelay + '1')  // record id 1
    .then(response1 => {

      return cy.request(urlWithDelay + '2')  // record id 2
      .then(response2 => {

        return cy.request(urlWithDelay + '3')  // record id 3
        .then(response3 => {

          return [response1.body.title, response2.body.title, response3.body.title]
        })
      })
    })
}

apiCalls().then(console.log)
  .should(results => {
    expect(results[0]).to.eq('delectus aut autem')
    expect(results[1]).to.eq('quis ut nam facilis et officia qui')
    expect(results[2]).to.eq('fugiat veniam minus')
  })



Sequential (rather than nested) calls
It turns out, after testing, that you don't need nested cy.request() calls, you can force the function to wait for all requests by using cy.then() (which was my original off-the-cuff answer BTW).
function apiCalls() {
  let api1
  let api2
  let api3

  const myApiBase = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'
  const urlWithDelay = 'https://app.requestly.io/delay/1000/' + myApiBase

  cy.request(urlWithDelay + '1')
    .then(response => { api1 = response.body.title })
  
  cy.request(urlWithDelay + '2')
    .then(response => { api2 = response.body.title })

  cy.request(urlWithDelay + '3')
    .then(response => { api3 = response.body.title })

  return cy.then(() => [api1, api2, api3])
}

apiCalls()
  .should(results => {
    expect(results[0]).to.eq('delectus aut autem')
    expect(results[1]).to.eq('quis ut nam facilis et officia qui')
    expect(results[2]).to.eq('fugiat veniam minus')
  })

So cy.then() behaves like async/await in plain Javascript.

I have used this way in a scenario which a request generates an access token for use on a following request, along the same function. It seems you can't access, for example, var api1 on the request that follows, as a param for it.  Is that correct?

You would have to put 2nd request in cy.then(() => {...}) type callback to use the token from the 1st request, which is pretty much the same as the nesting example given at the top.

Indeed, I was trying the sequential way, but only with nesting I got it working. Thanks for the info.

Technically, what's wrong is the early evaluation of the result you want in allTypesPresent.
cy.wrap(value-or-expression) always evaluates value-or-expression as soon as possible, and that occurs during the command queue setup, and before the commands have started running.
One way to defer evaluation is to wrap the expression in a function, and call the function when you want the result (i.e. at the return statement).
In your code const allTypesPresent = type1Present && type2Present && type3Present is evaluating too soon.
You can use cy.wrap(() => type1Present && type2Present && type3Present) to defer evaluation.
You then invoke the function at the point of return.
static areAllTypesFound(params) : Cypress.Chainable<boolean> {
    let idsType1 : number[];
    let idsType2 :number[];
    let idsType3 :number[];

    let [type1Present, type2Present, type3Present] = [false, false, false];

    // Here response = Cypress.Response<ItemType1 2 or 3>
    ApiCaller.getItemType1(param1).then((response) => {
        idsType1 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
        type1Present = idsType1.length > 0;
    }

    ApiCaller.getItemType2(param2).then((response) => {
        idsType2 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
        type2Present = idsType2.length > 0;
    }

    ApiCaller.getItemType3(param3).then((response) => {
        idsType3 = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
        type3Present = idsType3.length > 0;
    }

    return cy.wrap(() => type1Present && type2Present && type3Present) 
      .then(fn => fn());  // evaluate
} 

For convenience you can add a small custom command to do the same thing
Cypress.Commands.add('evaluate', (fn) => fn())

static areAllTypesFound(params) : Cypress.Chainable<boolean> {

  ...
  return cy.evaluate(() => type1Present && type2Present && type3Present);
}

P.S This solution is also present in other forms in the other answers, but I wanted to emphasize the idea of deferred evaluation, particularly WRT cy.wrap().

Using aliases
Usually an alias holds a single value, but we can build an array with a custom command
Cypress.Commands.add('saveToAlias', (aliasName, value) => {
  cy.get(`@${aliasName}`, {log:false})
    .then(values => values.concat(value))
    .as(aliasName)
})

The advantage is the API calls are decoupled from local variables, and the return value isn't needed - the alias can be accessed anywhere in the test.
static areAllTypesFound(params) : Cypress.Chainable<boolean> {

    cy.wrap([]).as('results')   // initialize

    // Common response handler, all API calls
    function checkResponse(response) {      
      const idsTypes = response.body.items.map((item) => item.id);
      cy.saveToAlias('results', idsTypes.length > 0)
    }

    ApiCaller.getItemType1(param1).then(checkResponse)
    ApiCaller.getItemType2(param2).then(checkResponse)
    ApiCaller.getItemType3(param3).then(checkResponse)
} 

static doStuff() : void {
    this.areAllTypesFound(params)

    cy.get('@results').then(results => {
      const allTypesPresent = results.every(result => result)  // all true?
      if(allTypesPresent) {
          // do something
       }else {
          // do something else
       }
    });

    // do more stuff only AFTER the above code is completed !
}


Thanks. I googled "early evaluation deferred evaluation typescript" to learn more. I got this link https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-lazy-evaluation-in-typescript and read it. Is this a good example or do you know of any better articles on the web?

Yes, it's short but illustrates concept. Also interesting in that example is the use of function wrappers around the parameters.

Another example in the Cypress docs is Cypress.Commands.addQuery where the return value is a function instead of a value. Contrast to Cypress.Commands.addCommand which just returns the value directly and needs a following .should() assertion to make it retry.

areAllTypesFound always returns false because the line where you assign that variable the values of  type1Present, type2Present, and type3Present is executed synchronously, whereas the getItemTypeX functions are asynchronous.  So at the point areAllTypesFound is assigned the value, all three of those variables are false.
Assuming getItemTypeX functions are added to the Cypress command chain (assuming they are using cy.X functions, they should), you can simply move that assignment into the final cy.wrap(), instead of assigning prior to that cy.wrap
...
return cy.then(() => {
  return type1Present && type2Present && type3Present;
});


I tried that, but cy.wrap() takes initial values not the final values.

I also tried  cy.then() to delay the final expression evaluation, but the problem is API responses can be delayed.

with the getItemTypeX functions returning Cypress commands?

Essentially getItemType are just cy.request() so I tried a live API but the result was flaky. If the inner command was cy.get() for example, each command would wait for the previous to finish but with cy.request() there is an added complication of the API call which could return at random times depending on network speed. The cy.request() seems to require explicit nesting to ensure completion of all the requests.

@agoff - Thank you. I added an example to show what the getItemTypeX function looks like. See getItemType1.

This is the error I get with your code - Type 'Chainable<() => boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Chainable'.
Types of property 'and' are incompatible.
Type 'Chainer<() => boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Chainer'.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.ts(2322)

Here is how I fixed the above error -
(1) change the return type of areAllTypesFound() FROM Chainable to Chainable<() => boolean>. (2) In doStuff(), areFoundBoolean is not a variable anymore, but a function. So, I call it in the IF block - if(areFoundBoolean()){.....}. That fixes it.

@agoff - Are there any limitations to your approach?

@agoff I tried cy.wrap() against the reproducible test, but it came back with threeundefined - the "early wrap" problem. I then switched cy.wrap() to cy.then() (since your syntax is more like a then callback than a wrap), and it got the correct results. I'll post that at the bottom of my answer.

Thanks y'all - modified my response to just omit the cy.wrap(). @MasterJoe - I'm not aware of any in the case of what you're trying to do - using cy.then() or cy.wrap(null) are pretty easy ways to "jump" into the Cypress command chain, so if you need to execute synchronous code at a specific time in the Cypress command chain, wrapping those commands in their own cy.then() block is a good way to go about it IMO.
